# keep it simple: Detect string/value inside array from many uncertain variables based on inputs' value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have the following lines of code:
*HTML:**

```html
<ul>
  <li id="ukVal"></li>
  <li id="hrgVal"></li>
  <li id="wrVal"></li>
</ul>
<input type='hidden' class='txtukuran' name='txtukuran' value='M/25'/>
<input type='hidden' class='txtwarna' name='txtwarna' value='Putih'/> 

<div class='hasil'></div>
```

**And, Javascript**:

```js
//array data
const m25kuning = { ukuran:"M/25", harga:"12000", warna:"Kuning" }; 
const m25putih  = { ukuran:"M/25", harga:"45000", warna:"Putih"  }; 
const m25hijau  = { ukuran:"M/25", harga:"30000", warna:"Hijau"  }; 
const m25biru   = { ukuran:"M/25", harga:"77000", warna:"Biru"   }; 

//get dan place data of m25kuning array into HTML above
document.getElementById("ukVal").innerHTML  = m25kuning.ukuran;
document.getElementById("hrgVal").innerHTML = m25kuning.harga;
document.getElementById("wrVal").innerHTML  = m25kuning.warna;

//I don't know how to continue the codes based on my question :)
//store innerHTML variable
var ukVal_set  = document.getElementById("ukVal").innerHTML;
var hrgVal_set = document.getElementById("hrgVal").innerHTML;
var wrVal_set  = document.getElementById("wrVal").innerHTML;

const varToString = varObj => Object.keys(varObj)[0];

const strNilai = varToString({m25kuning});
const strUpper = strNilai.toUpperCase();
var valPisahin = strUpper.substr(0,1) + "/" + strUpper.substr(1);
var ukValue    = valPisahin.substr(0,4);  // ukuran
var wrValue    = valPisahin.substr(4,10); // warna


if (ukValue=ukVal_set) {
  if (wrValue=hrgVal_set) {
    document.querySelector(".hasil").innerHTML = m25kuning.harga;
  }
}
```

*From the codes above*, I have `m25kuning`,`m25putih`, etc (actually I have more than 10 lines array data stored in variables).
After that, I will get each of the members of the array and place it to the `innerHTML` in **HTML** code above.

**THE QUESTION:**
How do I detect the name of the variables (if it is `m25kuning` or `m25putih` or `m25hijau` or `m25biru`) which **contains the values** *as in* `txtukuran` and `txtwarna` inputs.

Comment: *How do I detect the name of the variables* You can't. Instead of 4 different variables, create a single variable with these as indexes. Then just store the index in yet another variable.

Comment: what is the event chain of the seizure? your question lacks clarity...

Comment: wait!  I think my question is clear enough - don't let it closed, please. Wiktor Zychla has given me clue. That means that he understands my question :) I'm trying to code.

If I change the question, that can be duplicate and .. as YOU know, it simply is different of JUST to detect a single variable.

Comment: found it kinda hard to understand as well

Comment: 1) I didn't close your question. 2) sorry if my mind seems weaker than **Wiktor Zychla**'s, but I only half understand your question. What do you advise me to do to bring myself up to your intellectual level? hit myself on the head with a hammer?

Comment: no friend, I feel my English is not good enough to explain it for all people. Now, I can build a simple whatsApp shopping-cart system in blogspot without using hosting/database with this lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to store your data in a single object rather than 4 different variables:

```js
//array data
const data = {
  "m25kuning": {ukuran:"M/25", harga:"12000", warna:"Kuning"},
  "m25putih": {ukuran:"M/25", harga:"45000", warna:"Putih"},
  "m25hijau": {ukuran:"M/25", harga:"30000", warna:"Hijau"},
  "m25biru": {ukuran:"M/25", harga:"77000", warna:"Biru"},
};
```

You can reference individual data items by name:

```js
const m25kuning = data["m25kuning"];
//get dan place data of m25kuning array into HTML above
document.getElementById("ukVal").innerHTML = m25kuning.ukuran;
document.getElementById("hrgVal").innerHTML = m25kuning.harga;
document.getElementById("wrVal").innerHTML = m25kuning.warna;
```

You can then iterate over the "variables" (the properties in the data object) to search for what you need. Here's one way to accomplish that:

```js
const findData = (ukuran, warna) =>
    Object.values(data).find(
        value =>
            value.ukuran === ukuran &&
            value.warna === warna
    );

findData("M/25", "Kuning"); // returns {ukuran:"M/25", harga:"12000", warna:"Kuning"}
```

So, putting it back together (as best I can understand):

```js
var ukVal_set  = document.getElementById("ukVal").innerHTML;
var hrgVal_set = document.getElementById("hrgVal").innerHTML;
var wrVal_set  = document.getElementById("wrVal").innerHTML;

const matchingData = findData(ukVal_set, wrVal_set);
document.querySelector(".hasil").innerHTML = matchingData.harga;
```

Comment: wow!  I must write many variables with its possibilities. but, this is more simple as I do. Done! work like a charm !!! now I can supply more variables inside the `data`.